# multiline docker run command

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline:

```
    node('some_vm') {
        stage('Build'){

                sh '''\\
                docker run --name my_container --privileged -v /dev/vboxdrv:/dev/vboxdrv\\
                -v /usr/bin/vboxheadless:/usr/bin/vboxheadless\\
                -v /usr/bin/vboxmanage:/usr/bin/vboxmanage\\
                -v /lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest/:/lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest/\\
                -v /lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf/:/lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf/\\
                -v /lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/:/lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/\\ 
                -v /usr/lib/virtualbox/:/usr/lib/virtualbox/\\
                -v /etc/udev/rules.d/60-vboxdrv.rules:/etc/udev/rules.d/60-vboxdrv.rules\\ 
                -v /sbin/lsmod:/sbin/lsmod\\
                -v /sbin/modprobe:/sbin/modprobe\\ 
                -v /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0\\
                -v /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0\\
                -v /usr/bin/vboxsdl:/usr/bin/vboxsdl\\
                -v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0\\
                -v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcaca.so.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcaca.so.0\\
                -v /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libslang.so.2:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libslang.so.2\\
                -v /home/jenkins/workspace/test/:/config/\\
                -v /home/jenkins/workspace/test/vms:/root/VirtualBox\\ VMs/\\
                -e VAGRANT_1 -e VAGRANT_2 -e VAGRANT_3 test_image\\
                '''
        }
}
```

But it always fails with error:

```
"docker run" requires at least 1 argument(s).
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I tried different ways to achive multiline docker run command, but so far no luck.

Maybe somebody has some thoughts about it?

Comment: remove \\ and add \ at the end of each line.

Comment: I tried this approach, but it doesn't work.    /kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/\ 
                                 ^

1 error

Comment: give a space at end and use only single \ and some issue with last line -v /home/jenkins/workspace/test/vms:/root/VirtualBox\\ VMs/\\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by using JSON format in Dockerfile for CMD directive. It seems like bash inside container has limitations and therefore bash cannot be handled properly. I also decided to refer to Docker API instead of using command line items: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple groovy script:

```
node {
    stage('check java') {
        sh "java -version "
    }
}
```

Multilines in shellscript:

```
echo "hello-world" && \
    echo "foo-bar"
```

then press the "up" arrow to get the command from your history, and it'll show;

```
echo "hello-world" && echo "foo-bar"
```

Rewriting your command:

```
node('some_vm') {
        stage('Build'){

                sh "docker run --name my_container --privileged -v /dev/vboxdrv:/dev/vboxdrv \
                -v /usr/bin/vboxheadless:/usr/bin/vboxheadless \
                -v /usr/bin/vboxmanage:/usr/bin/vboxmanage \
                -v /lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest/:/lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest/ \
                -v /lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf/:/lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf/ \
                -v /lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/:/lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/ \ 
                -v /usr/lib/virtualbox/:/usr/lib/virtualbox/ \
                -v /etc/udev/rules.d/60-vboxdrv.rules:/etc/udev/rules.d/60-vboxdrv.rules \ 
                -v /sbin/lsmod:/sbin/lsmod \
                -v /sbin/modprobe:/sbin/modprobe \ 
                -v /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 \
                -v /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 \
                -v /usr/bin/vboxsdl:/usr/bin/vboxsdl \
                -v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0 \
                -v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcaca.so.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcaca.so.0 \
                -v /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libslang.so.2:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libslang.so.2 \
                -v /home/jenkins/workspace/test/:/config/ \
                -v /home/jenkins/workspace/test/vms:/root/VirtualBox \
                -e VAGRANT_1 -e VAGRANT_2 -e VAGRANT_3 test_image"
        }
}
```

Comment: WorkflowScript: 4: unexpected char: '\' @ line 4, column 102.
    -v /dev/vboxdrv:/dev/vboxdrv \